# Xamarin Forms FileSystemWatcher

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, filesystemwatcher, notimplementedexception

i need to watch a folder that are inside my ios/android application.

I would like to use `FileSystemWatcher`.

This is my code:

```
var DocFolder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
var InboxFolder = DocFolder + "/Inbox";

 FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher() {
     Path = InboxFolder,
     NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastAccess | NotifyFilters.LastWrite | NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName,
     Filter = "*.*",
     EnableRaisingEvents = true
 };

watcher.Created += (object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e) => {
    // do stuff
};
```

When the `FileSystemWatcher` is initializated this error is triggered:

```
System.NotImplementedException: The method or operation is not implemented.
```

How can I make this works?

There is another way to watch a folder?

Thank you!

Comment: You can use `Android.OS.FileObserver` for Android. For iOS you might look on the Xamarin documentation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`FileSystemWatcher` is a .NET Framework-based class which is currently **not implemented** in Xamarin, although the API is available in .NET Standard 2.0.

In **UWP** you can create a `StorageFolderQuery` with `ContentChanged` event handler to observe changes in a given folder. See documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Storage.Search.StorageFolderQueryResult#Windows_Storage_Search_StorageFolderQueryResult_ContentsChanged).

**Android** has it's own alternative implementation in the form of [`Android.OS.FileObserver`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/FileObserver.html).

**iOS** does not seem to have anything out of the box, so this will probably either require you to find a library that does this job for you or to implement such functionality yourself, albeit in a less efficient manner than if it were built-in to the SDK.